# Mount amplified cable splitter in wall

Tags: coaxial-cable

Is mounting the PCT-MA2-P2 behind an interior wall a code violation?

The power (15VDC 250mA) to the PCT-MA2-P2 is input via RG6 coax cable with F type connector.  The media room on the second floor has coax from the master bedroom closet on the first floor.  I want to feed the antenna from the attic directly to the input of the PCT-MA2-P2 in the wall of the media room below, and then connect the coax cable from the master bedroom closet to an output port of the PCT-MA2-P2 to carry the antenna signal to the master bedroom closet.  There it will connect to the input of a similar device with eight output ports connected to RG6 cables distributing the antenna signal to the other rooms of the house.

The PCT-MA2-P2 will be accessible through the hole where the wall plate is mounted.  The wall plate will have two F type ports: one to feed power to the PCT-MA2-P2 and one connected to the other output of the PCT-MA2-P2 to bring the antenna signal to the media room TV.

For aesthetics I'd prefer only adding another cable to the view as opposed to three cables and the PCT-MA2-P2.  The second picture does not show the PCT-MA2-P2 device in the wall nor the second output cable connected to it which is going to the central distribution point.  I will probably adhere a piece of furring strip to the inside of the back wall with Liquid Nails® and screw the device to it so it can be seen through the hole.  This is Texas, USA.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would not bury it inside a wall regardless of whether it violates code or not. These things will, sooner or later, need repaired/replaced. I would put in a small access panel in front of it to facilitate easier repair/replacement when the time comes. If the home is sold and this is hidden in the wall, imagine how hard it will be for the new owner to troubleshoot/find the issue.

For example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Elmdor-10-in-x-10-in-Steel-Hinged-Metal-Wall-or-Ceiling-Access-Panel-DW10X10PC-SDL